# VirtualBox headless caused high CPU load on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, virtualbox, mac, headless

When I run a CentOS linux VM on VirtualBox in headless mode the CPU continuously spikes up to about 80% for a couple of seconds at a time with a short 1 or 2 second gap and then does it again. Even with the machine idling, no other application running and the CentOS system doing nothing. If I change it and run it normally, e.g. head mode, then this effect doesn't happen. It would appear to be the opendirectoryd, cfprefsd and notifyd along with the VBoxHeadless process causing the majority of the load during the spikes.

I have tried this on two MacBook Pro's both running Mac OS X 10.9.3 and it has the same effect on both.

Has anyone else observed this behaviour and know how to prevent it?

[image: Activity monitor showing cycling CPU spikes]

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this? My MBA sounds like a jet engine when I am using Ubuntu server in Virtual Box. I checked the server stats and it is using very little processor power.

Comment: Only solution was to not use it in headless mode.

Comment: Same problem, has anyone reported this as a bug to the VirtualBox folk?

Comment: @andrewdixon how can I run without the headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issue dealing with a Virtual Box machine for Minikube. In order to solve it, I opened up VirtualBox App and gave the virtual machine 8 GB memory instead of 2 GB. *(My Mac has 32GB installed, so plenty to take from)*. That did the trick.. Now it is down at a low CPU again.